# logstash input json remove root for elasticsearch indexing

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

Here is the json structure coming out from my input.

```
"path" => "my/path",
    "@timestamp" => 2017-09-28T07:54:25.482Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "linuxbox",
       "message" => "{\"top_val\":{\"birthday\":\"07/12/1991\",\"country\":\"India\"}"
```

Once i index this data to elasticsearch , i need to access this field in _source as `top_val.birthday`. How can i remove this top_val so that i can access the fields directly from _source. I know this can be done with arbitrary ruby code. But i believe there must be better ways to do it. Please help me with this.

Comment: What is the problem with accessing like top_val.birthday ?? Your document is such that you have to access like that only..

Answer (score 0):

Drop into ruby, loop across all the fields in `top_val` and move them to the root of the event.